# UPDATE данных в БД

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Пытаюсь сделать UPDATE через форму, но выводит почему-то вместо истины ложь!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<title>Соединяемся с БД</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
//Некоторые хостинги не поддерживают прямую передачу переменных! Поэтому существует от них защита такого рода!//
if (isset($_POST['name']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
}
if (isset($_POST['lastname']))
{
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
}
if (isset($_POST['dol']))
{
$dol = $_POST['dol'];
}
if (isset($_POST['id']))
{
$id = $_POST['id'];
}

//Создание Коннекта к БД..//
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","alex","12345");
mysql_query("set names 'cp1251' ",$db);//mysql_query формирует запрос к БД на вывод правильного отабражения кодировки//
mysql_select_db("firstbd",$db);//Выбираем определенную базу данных//
//Создание Коннекта к БД..//

$result = mysql_query ("UPDATE firma SET (name,lastnamе,dol,id) VALUES ('$name','$lastname','$dol','$id')");

if ($result == 'true')
{
echo "Информация в базе обновлена успешно!";
}

else
{
echo "Информация в базе не обновлена!";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Алексей31, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: не ну эт издевательство, мы так не прочитаем и не поможем Вам, отформатируйте код.

Comment: Чувствуете? Фрилансом запахло

Comment: > //Некоторые хостинги не поддерживают прямую передачу переменных! Поэтому существует от них защита такого рода!//

Это на некоторых, блин, хостингах, есть защита от прямых инъекций, которая здесь аннулируется ударом сапога.

Answer (score 1):

Строковые переменные нужно заключать в кавычки. И откажитесь от использования mysql_ в пользу mysqli_ или PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Замечательно, а где ваш where? Обновляете тоже все без разбора?

Да и данная "защита от хостингов" тоже внушает... 
Совет вам - почитайте про mysql_real_escape_string и подобное. А так же про sql инъекции и чем они грозят. Ну и прежде чем здесь задавать ТАКОЙ вопрос - можно было хотя бы почитать http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html